# escapeHtml4() security issue

Tags: apex

I am getting security when I use below code in class. Please let me know how to resolve this.

```
stringVar = stringVar.escapeHtml4();
```

or

```
stringVar = stringVar.escapeSingleQuotes();
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more of your code so the community can see what else might be the issue since calling escapeHtml4 isn't in itself going to cause Checkmarx to complain. Assuming it is a Checkmarx scan that is complaining. Your questions do not include enough context and you are making assumptions about what the issue is, which leads to either getting no answers or getting answers that themselves make assumptions. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/280323/edit) your question and add all the missing details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to follw the below syntax.

```
String str = 'Some HTML Text <br>';
System.debug('Before Escape:'+str);
String escapeString = str.escapeHtml4();
System.debug('After Escape:'+escapeString);
```

Comment: I was getting security issue as "variable need to sanitize before using"  for stringVar = stringVar.escapeSingleQuotes(); Will your suggestion resolve this ?